# Pandas: how to get only values of columns that value_counts() equals N

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataFrame:

```
df = 
    a   b   c   d   e
0   0   1   2   3   4
1   1   2   3   0   4
2   2   3   1   4   0
```

I would like to get the values that occur N times in a certain column.

For example, if I want to get all the values that occur 2 times in column "e", i would get `result = [4]`, and if I would like to get all the values that occur 1 time in column "d", I would get `result = [3,0,4]`.

I can do `df['e'].value_counts() == 2` but that gives a True/False series. I would just want to get the values in "True".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you did returns a True/False series, so we need to use this to get the index values!

```
col = 'd'
n = 1
df[col].value_counts() == n
# 3    True
# 0    True
# 4    True
# Name: d, dtype: bool
```

To get the indeces that have `True` behind them, we can do:

```
df[col].value_counts().index[df[col].value_counts() == n]
# Int64Index([3, 0, 4], dtype='int64')
```

To create a list, we only need to use `list()`:

```
list(df[col].value_counts().index[df[col].value_counts() == n])
# [3, 0, 4]
```

EDIT:
You can assign `val_counts = df[col].value_counts()` and use this like so (or see the answer from @jezrael):

```
list(val_counts.index[val_counts == n])
# [3, 0, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter `index` values after [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
s = df['e'].value_counts()

L = s.index[s.eq(2)].tolist()
print (L)
[4]
```

---

```
s = df['d'].value_counts()

L = s.index[s.eq(1)].tolist()
print (L)
[0, 4, 3]
```